# Configure Greeting Message on Einstein Bot before connecting to Agent without Prechat form

Tags: einstein-chatbot

I have saved the user data such as the name on the custom field on LiveChatTranscript.I would like to show the name when the bot is connecting. Now it shows "Hello Guest " without pre-chat from. Instead of pre-chat from how to fetch the name from LiveChatTranscript object and show it to the user? ,or edit the greeting to show something else.?

[image: Chat greeting]

Comment: Without Prechat form how will you get username or details? Are you using this in the community?

Comment: I passed value to the Live Chat Transcript from the external site by modifying Embedded Service Code Snippet.